# Windows 10 won't boot without USB stick

Tags: boot, usb, windows-10

I have just installed Windows 10 final (from USB stick as my laptop does not have DVD). Everything went without a problem. The computer restarts correctly while an USB device is inserted (it does not have to be a bootable drive, it can even be an empty USB stick).

If I remove the USB drive, Windows boot does not complete.

Safe mode boots ok without the stick.
Boot log without the USB stick ends like this:

```
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\UsbHub3.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\RTKVHD64.sys
```

Successful Boot log (with stick in) goes past:

```
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\UsbHub3.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\RTKVHD64.sys
BOOTLOG_NOT_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\dxgkrnl.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\USBSTOR.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\monitor.sys
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\hidusb.sys
```

Any ideas on what to remove/change/proceed? I really don't want to restore/reinstall.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to add more info: The main boot drive has 2 partitions:Sytems reserved:500MB (SYSTEM,ACTIVE,PRIMARY), and the second is 200GB (BOOT,PAGE,CRASH DUMP, PRIMARY).

Comment: nice having the 2 boot logs, because often people will find the last thing in the bootlog  (RTKVHD64.sys realtek audio) and figure this is the driver thing causing the problem. Instead it is usually the next thing that was loading up (dxgkrnl.sys) which is a nvidia driver right?  Then USBstor which is the generic 2.0 kind of usb driver. Safe mode probably does not load all the video driver stuff (although it has at times) But will load usb.   Now what happens when it hits that point, what error?    How does a usb stick change how a video driver works? when they share the same IRQ.

Comment: When there is no USB stick in a port (any USB port) Windows does not get past the blue Windows logo. The CPU is working extra at that point (cooler starting) then it slows down and stays there. No error messages. Waited about 15 minutes. In the device manager there are no conflicts that I can see.

Comment: That is truely crasiest problem of the month. Did you have any USB key dongle things alladin sentinel , any usb security things , password on stick, encryption tools, or any special programs that before update existed? Any odd "filters" which are added driver from other programs tossed into  drivers for a feature.  If there was nothng at all you can think of along those lines the only thing i can think of is Crasily run the driver sweeper specific to gpu software removal, and test with the video drivers gone and running compatability. A clone backup first would give you a way to retract.

Comment: Again thanks for your help. Upvoted. Solved as stated below. The only thing that I can think of was that on a laptop with Intel H87 Chipset and Samsung EVO 840SSD, Windows did not recognize my Intel SMBus controller and SD card. For both I have pointed to the folder with the 8.1 drivers and Windows recognized them ok (no conflicts). So I installed the Chipset Utility (for w 8.1) and all was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. Thanks Psycogeek for the hint that it could be USB related. **I have installed the Intel Chipset Utility**, even if it says it is only up to Windows 8.1 for now (August 2nd 2015). And now a stick is no longer necessary to boot into Windows.

For everyone with this type of problems take a bootlog capture with a bad start and a good start. The bootlog is usally stored in

```
c:\Windows\ntbtlog.txt.
```

The bootlogs recorder in the text file are separated by a date. The problem is one of the listings that

Comment: can you post the link to the specific Intel Chipset Utility? I can't seem to find just one. thanks!

Comment: @AnimaSola Usually its here, but you have to choose your hardware product (prob. the first will work): https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/1145/Intel-Chipset-Software-Installation-Utility

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens if you don’t create a new partition on the boot drive when you install windows 10. It will store some of the boot information in the USB stick and you won’t be able to boot without it.  When you select the boot drive, make sure it doesn’t say “unallocated” for the os partition. Create a new partition. The installation will create two partitions. One of them is titled “system reserved”. Install windows on the other “larger” partition.

Sometimes startup repair can fix this, but sometimes not. Boot to windows with the USB inserted and restart with windows boot options enabled. If you can’t repair it, it is probably best to just reinstall with the new partition created and you will not have this problem anymore.