# Cannot boot windows 10 without bootable usb

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, bios

At first, my machine was run out of battery then it shut down or hibernate (I'm not sure). Then I start the system again but the display show black screen with a flickering cursor on the left top of the screen. I searched and found this link http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options that my situation is **Your PC won't start and you haven't created a recovery drive**.
Then I created a usb to boot the machine. I plugged my usb to my machine and it was started. Then I tried to reset but it did not work. From that I cannot start the windows without the usb anymore.

I use windows 10 pro that upgraded from windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/949331/windows-10-wont-boot-without-usb-stick) to see what your problem is. And recheck your usb boot configuration (maybe USB is chosen to install MBR):

> [I was able to solve the issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/windows-10-tech-preview-does-not-boot-without-usb/9a97424d-ca03-4f4d-ae84-963abe46d579). I founnd that the issue was due to the
>   fact that I did not choose "GPT" when creating the USB drive with
>   Rufus. It was always selected as MBR. Once I selected the partition
>   scheme correctly the installation completed and the computer did boot
>   without the USB connected.